# How to check if a string contains an other string

Tags: python, list, if-statement, filter

This is my file:

```
#This is TEST-data
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,Lon,Man,Lon,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,Lon,Lon,Man,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,Lon,Lon,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,Lon,Lon,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,3,Mad,Sev,Sev,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,GGG,Mad,Sev,Mad1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-40,GGG,Mad,Bar,1,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00
```

When I run below code I get an empty return. That could be because my code doesnt seem to know that Man is in Manchester for example and Sev is in Sevilla.
I assume the problem arises in `condition_1`

```
path = r'c:\data\ELK\Desktop\test_data_countries.txt'

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']

def filter_row(row):
    if len(row) > 2 and row[2].isdigit():
            amount_of_cities = int(row[2])        
            cities_to_check = row[3:3+amount_of_cities]    
            condition_1 =  any(city in cities_to_check for city in cities_to_filter)  
                    
            return condition_1

with open (path, 'r') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(output_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,Lon,Man,Lon,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,Lon,Lon,Man,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,3,Mad,Sev,Sev,1,1,1
```

Comment: Your code is checking whether "Manchester" is in "Man", while it should be the other way around.

Comment: Is it always going to be the first 3 chars in the name like Man for Manchester or there could be a possibility for something like Mhr or Mcr for Manchester.

Comment: @SandeepKumar It could be something different yes. Not always the first 3.

Comment: @TangerCity then what I would probably do, since these are comma-separated values load them into a pandas dataframe and check different possibilities and maybe keep a dict (kind of map Man -> Manchester). There could be other approaches to make it even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you can split every line with .split() function, this function splits strings respect to parameter you gave, if you don't give parameter, it will seperate the string for spaces. Then it will return a list, so you should assign it to a list. then control if "man" in list or "sev" in list.

```
for line in file:   
   myList=line.split(",")
   if "man" in myList or "sev" in myList:
       #blabla
```

Comment: @Barmar good point. Looks like I had a brain fart :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to match the string `Man` with `Manchester`.

You can use the following to match with the first three characters only:

```
import csv
path = 'Pdata.txt'

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']

def filter_row(row):
    if len(row) > 2 and row[2].isdigit():
            amount_of_cities = int(row[2])        
            cities_to_check = row[3:3+amount_of_cities]
            #print(cities_to_check)
            condition_1 =  any(city[:3] in cities_to_check for city in cities_to_filter)  
            
            return condition_1

with open (path, 'r') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(output_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

To match for any characters and not just the first three, you can use list comprehension using both lists to find for any matching rows.

So, if you have `cities_to_check` as `["Man", "vil"]`, matching will contain both `['Sevilla', 'Manchester']` and then you can use `len(matching) != 0` as the return criteria to get the desired result.

```
cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']    
cities_to_check = ["Man", "vil"]
matching = [city2 for city2 in cities_to_filter if any(city1 in city2 for city1 in cities_to_check)]
```

Comment: What if its not always the first 3 but it could be anything?

Comment: I have updated the code to handle for substring match at any location.